# Using FeatureCollection in Configurable Map Viewer?

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

I have searched everywhere online on How to use featureCollection in the operationalLayers of CMV.

Is any sample code available?

Answer (score 0):

@geebengs CMV does not currently support using a FeatureCollection when first creating a Feature Layer within the `operationalLayers` of viewer.js. That is a good enhancement and relatively simple to add. I will add it to the list of enhancements for CMV.

Depending on the source of the features in the FeatureCollection, you can also add them to a Feature layer or a Graphics layer using a custom widget.